# Associate Duplicate Rows with corresponding active roe (row 1)

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server: Duplicate result set with RowNo

```
SourceID    FullName    RowNo   UniqueID
----------------------------------------------------------------
29757   NORBERT OVERWEG 1   29757

53736   NORBERT OVERWEG 2   NULL

47636   NORBERT OVERWEG 3   NULL

25685   NORBERT OVERWEG 4   NULL

53579   NORBERT OVERWEG 5   NULL

42301   NORBERT OVERWEG 6   NULL

49717   SECION CHAN 1   49717

51212   SECION CHAN 2   NULL
```

How can I replace NULLs with corresponding ID from Row 1?

Expected Result:

```
SourceID    FullName    RowNo   UniqueID
-------------------------------------------------

29757   NORBERT OVERWEG 1   29757

53736   NORBERT OVERWEG 2   29757

47636   NORBERT OVERWEG 3   29757

25685   NORBERT OVERWEG 4   29757

53579   NORBERT OVERWEG 5   29757

42301   NORBERT OVERWEG 6   29757

49717   SECION CHAN 1   49717

51212   SECION CHAN 2   49717
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
UPDATE MyTable a
set UniqueID = 
    (select uniqueid from MyTable b
     where rowno = 1 and a.FullName = b.FullName)
where UniqueID is null
```